# how do you use return() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Can somebody please teach me how to do return? I am doing a course and I just don't understand what return is for and how to use it :(

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/

Comment: As you're in a class, I suggest you talk to your teacher or a tutor; the *really* basic elements of programming can't be taught a StackOverflow question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

return is used when defining function so it returns the result of this function.

example:

```
def test():
   return(1)
```

it returns 1

```
def test2(a,b):
    return(a+b)
```

it returns the sum of the two values

Comment: None of them should have parentheses involved though.

Answer (score 0):

A return statement is used to end the execution of the function call and “returns” the result.
The statements after the return statement are not executed

For example:

```
def cube(x):
   r = x**3
   return r
```

Maybe this could help you as well:

[Print and Return, What's the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)